# Почему если из contenteditable блока удалить весь текст снова набрать его не получается?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui

Создаю блоки с `contenteditable: true`.
Если из блока удалить весь текст, то невозможно снова набирать текст в этом блоке. Почему так?
И еще подскажите, как выделять текст? Знаю, что выделение блокирует `draggable()`. Может, это как-то можно обойти?
Еще если блок создавать пустым, в нем ничего не печатается. Почему?

```
var dynDiv = $('<div>')
    .attr({'id': 'div_' + dname_id++,'contenteditable': 'true'})
      .css({
        'width': '50px',
        'height': '20px'
      })
      .addClass('resize')
$('#container').append(dynDiv);
//-------------------------------------------------------//
dynDiv.resizable({
  ghost: true
})
dynDiv.draggable({
  containment: 'parent'
});
```

Вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/japfdL1t/5/. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все проблемы из-за неправильного расположения элементов.
Если оставить только родительский div и удалить все его содержимое то, редактирование можно продолжить и после удаления всего текста. Я бы рекомендовал вам добавить отдельный, дополнительный div для текста и растянуть его на ширину родительского элемента.

```
var dynDiv = $('<div class="content resize"><div class="text" contenteditable=true></div></div>');
```

Например, так

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dname_id = 1;

  $("#btn2").click(function() {

    var dynDiv = $('<div class="content resize"><div class="text" contenteditable=true></div></div>');

    $('#container').append(dynDiv);
    //-------------------------------------------------------//
    dynDiv.resizable({
      ghost: true
    })
    dynDiv.draggable({
      containment: 'parent'
    });

    dynDiv.click(function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();

      /*$('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');*/

      /*$('.selected').attr('contenteditable', 'true' )*/

    });
  });
  /*--------------------------------------------*/

});
```

```css
.resize {
  background-color: #29e;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#container {
  box-shadow: 4px 0px 18px -1px #0000ff;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
}
.selected {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  /*box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);*/
}
.content {
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
}
.text {
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn2">new div</button>
<br/>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="c" contenteditable=true>g</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/japfdL1t/7/)

Comment: А как сделать.что бы текст вводился при draggable()?

Comment: Нужно установить фокус на элемент со свойством contenteditable 

https://jsfiddle.net/japfdL1t/9/